# Would a PN junction diode work if we would polarise it without putting specific aluminium material at the sides of the P and the N?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In schematic of PN junction diode, we see aluminium on the P and the N side.

Would the diode work if we would polarise the PN junction diode, without putting some aluminium at the sides ?

If so, what is the role of the aluminium on the sides of the PN junction diode ?

example of schematic :

[image]

Comment: When asking about pictures or schematics, post the thing you are referring to. But have you heard of Schottky diodes? It is not made up of a PN junction but a metal and silicon junction. Doesn't that make you wonder how anyone ever connects metal wires to semiconductors without constantly turning everything into a Schottky diode? That's a hint that there's a lot more to make a Schottky diode (or any diode since you need metal leads) than just putting metal against silicon.

Comment: @DKNguyen : PN junction diode is something very simple so the schematic is known from everybody. Also, PN junction diode is a very classical stuff, so the schematic could be seen in all books, and everywhere on the web. So there is no need to show a schematic for this specific question. I don't know about hte Schottky diode and my question is not on the subject of Schottky diode (else I would have used this word)

Comment: The part about "*we see aluminium on the P and the N side*" is something very specific and you'll find that it is something not shown on the vast majority of PN junction diagrams.

Comment: @DKNguyen : I have added a schematic.

Comment: Thanks.  I know your question is not about Schottky diodes, but carefully read that part again and see how it pertains to your question. A schottky diode is made from silicon against metal. Do you see any parts of your PN junction where silicon also meets metal? Doesn't that make you wonder how anyone ever connects metal to a semiconductor without turning into a schottky diode?

Comment: @DKNguyen : I think that you have understood that if I ask the question, this is because I don't master the subject. Playing the role of the "professor" as you do, by asking questions, does not help me understand why we see contact parts in diode. Let's see if somebody has an idea and would like to *share* the explanation.

Comment: I wasn't trying to play the role of professor as much as pointing out that Schottky diodes exist (if you did not already know they exist) and then trying to get you to wonder about it yourself. Because the question is a lot more interesting if you come up with it yourself rather. It's rather boring if someone just tell you that's the way things are. That question itself isn't the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "polarise" the junction? The aluminum contact allows you to connect to the semiconductor. Your wires arent silicon, they are some metal, often copper. You have to connect that to the semiconductor somehow. If you remove the aluminum how do you propose we do that?

Comment: @Matt : polarise means apply a votage difference to the pn junction. Why not putting wire copper directly to the pn junction, without using aluminium ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian If your question is about why aluminum was chosen specifically rather than any other metal, please edit your question to say so. That's a fairly straightforward answer that should be addressed in any introduction to semiconductor devices text. The reason aluminum was chosen is almost entirely because of its workfunction, and the fact that its other properties don't otherwise prohibit it from being used. If I get time I will write up an answer. Its what part of the existing answer addresses but doesn't get into the details about.

Comment: @Matt : unfortunatley, book deal with theoretical aspects : I see nothing on concrete aspects

Comment: @Mathieu What book do you have?

Comment: @Matt : this one : https://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/physique-semiconducteurs-et-composants-electroniques-cours-et-exercices

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Schottky diodes?

Unlike a PN diode, a Schottky diode is made up of a metal-silicon junction. Do you see anywhere in your PN diode diagram (or any semiconductor if you think about it) where there is also a metal-silicon interface. Knowing that, doesn't that make you wonder how anyone connects metal leads to semiconductors at all without constantly turning everything into a Schottky diode? That is a hint that there is a lot more to making a Schottky diode (or conversely making a metal connection to a semiconductor) than just putting two material against each other.

In other words, you can't take for granted that connecting a metal to silicon will turn out to be a resistive connection that can conduct electrons in both directions as we are typically accustomed to when connecting wires up to things. The existence of a Schottky diode indicates that it could also turn out to be a rectifying junction. What determines this is how smoothly the bandgaps of the two materials roll into each other at the interface.

What you are looking at in the aluminum-silicon interface is called an "Ohmic contact". An Ohmic contact is when a junction (in this case between metal and silicon) has been prepared to form either a "regular" resistive connection rather than a rectifying junction (i.e. a diode).

I am not a semiconductor engineer so I can't say if that material has to be aluminum, but that aluminum contact is there because it can be prepared to form a resistive junction, and being metal itself, you can connect metal leads/wires to it and still expect it to it behave as a resistive contact without needing to think.

If that metal contact was not already prepared for you in the diode (or any semiconductor device), and you tried to connect a metal lead/wire directly to the silicon, you would have to worry about whether it will turn out to be an ohmic contact or a rectifying junction. But this is a case where the devil is in the details so even if the semiconductor was provided without the aluminum contact and you connected an aluminum wire to it yourself, it would not work since  surface preparation and material composition really, really, really matters.

Comment: Have you read the question : "Would a PN junction diode work if we would polarise it without putting specific aluminium material at the sides of the P and the N?" ? Also, my example is made by a professor of semiconductor physics for which I followed the course a few years ago. This is a "typical" PN junction diode. You are very vague on ohmic contact and don't really explain anything.

Comment: This is why I tried to prod you with the Schottky diode thing. I explained what an ohmic contact when I said "regular resistive connection". What's happening is you're taking for granted that you can just connect a wire (piece of metal) to a piece of doped silicon and and not have it do anything funny like suddenly turn into a diode. You can't assume that putting metal connection against silicon will conduct electrons in both directions in and out of the silicon as we are normally used to when we connect a wire up to something.

Comment: It's kind of a travesty that the existence of Ohmic contacts aren't even mentioned at the same time PN junction are mentioned because for most people all you need to know is that they are a thing.